# Get records not present in another table with a specific user id

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this table (**a**)

[image]

And this table (**b**)

[image]

Now I have to get all records from **A** which are not present in **B** (**a.id** not present as **b.idDomanda**) and where **B.idUser** is not **1**. So In this case, it should return *only id 2* from a, but it returns 1 and 2.

This is my Query

```
SELECT a.* FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.idDomanda WHERE ( b.idUser <> 1 OR b.idUser IS NULL ) GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Not in `b` for every user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move the condition on `b` to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON a.id = b.idDomanda and b.idUser <> 1
WHERE b.idUser IS NULL
GROUP BY a.id;
```

The `group by` suggests that you might want to use `not exists` instead:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where a.id = b.idDomanda and b.idUser <> 1
                 );
```

Comment: This is my solution.

SELECT a.* FROM a WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT idDomanda FROM b WHERE b.idUser = 1 )

Comment: I would suggest instead:  `SELECT a.* FROM a WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT idDomanda FROM b WHERE b.idUser = 1 AND idDomanda IS NOT NULL)`.  `SELECT DISTINCT` with an `IN` subquery is unnecessary, and the code will behave unexpectedly if any of the `iddomanda` are `NULL` (which is why I recommend using `NOT EXISTS`).

Answer (score 0):

There should be no results given your data set.

All records from A which are not present in B (a.id not present as b.idDomanda) 
Given the test data set all of A is in fact IN b.idDomanda... even when filtering out userId = 1.

but as the previous person pointed out that is the query to check.